# How To Build Custom Linux Distribution? Read below description

Tags: java, linux

I am having an application that runs on JVM. So, I need to build custom linux with JVM and my application that comes with installation.

Comment: I googled for "Custom Linux Distribution create", the rest is for you to make sense out of.

Comment: I think you're looking for *remastering* a Linux Live CD. Google that. Most major distros provide tools to do that, Ubuntu, Suse, Fedora. Do your homework before coming here.

Comment: I hope that you have *thoroughly* researched the implications of Linux'es GPL license ...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

- http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ - let's you build your own Linux distribution. It a little overhead, IMO, since you have...
- [Red Hat's Kickstarter](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) - use Red Hat, but with custom install script which will be able to install a JVM and your app automatically, during installation.
- Ubuntu has [preliminary support](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html) for Kickstarter as well, so you're not limited to Red Hat.

I don't think you need custom Linux Distribution for your use case. Just take one of the well-tested, supported distros out there (Red Hat, Ubuntu, Debian) and create an automate installation script. This way your app will be live right after installation, and you'll still get the benefit of having support, package manager etc.